# OpenAI API error: "You tried to access openai.ChatCompletion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0"

Tags: python, pip, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am currently working on a chatbot, and as I am using Windows 11 it does not let me migrate to newer OpenAI library or downgrade it. Could I replace the `ChatCompletion` function with something else to work on my version?

This is the code:

```
import openai

openai.api_key = "private"

def chat_gpt(prompt):
    response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
    )
    return response.choices[0].message['content'].strip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        user_input = input("You: ")
        if user_input.lower() in ["quit", "exit", "bye"]:
            break
        response = chat_gpt(user_input)
        print("Bot:", response)
```

And this is the full error:

> ...
> You tried to access openai.ChatCompletion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API.
>
> You can run `openai migrate` to automatically upgrade your codebase to use the 1.0.0 interface.
>
> Alternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g. <pip install openai==0.28>
>
> A detailed migration guide is available here: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742

I tried both upgrading and downgrading through pip.

Comment: Have you tried the migration guide? https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742

Answer (score 13):

Try updating to the latest and using:

```py
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI(
    # defaults to os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY")
    api_key="private",
)

def chat_gpt(prompt):
    response = client.chat.completions.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
        messages=[{"role": "user", "content": prompt}]
    )
    return response.choices[0].message.content.strip()
```

[Link](https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742)

EDIT: `message.['content']` -> `message.content` on the return of this function, as a `message object is not subscriptable` error is thrown while using `message.['content']`. Also, update link from pointing to the `README` (subject to change) to migration guide specific to this code.

Answer (score 6):

#### Problem

**The method name you're trying to use doesn't work with the OpenAI Python SDK version `1.0.0` or newer.**

The old SDK (i.e., version `0.28`) works with the following method name:

```
client.ChatCompletion.create
```

The new SDK (i.e., version `1.0.0` or newer) works with the following method name:

```
client.chat.completions.create
```

*Note: Be careful because the API is case-sensitive (i.e., `client.Chat.Completions.create` will not work with the new SDK version).*

#### Solution

Try this:

```
import os
from openai import OpenAI
client = OpenAI()
OpenAI.api_key = os.getenv('OPENAI_API_KEY')

completion = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
  messages=[
    {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Hello!"}
  ]
)

print(completion.choices[0].message.content)
```

Comment: not working: OpenAIError: The api_key client option must be set either by passing api_key to the client or by setting the OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable

Comment: client = OpenAI(api_key=key)

Comment: @leila I'll take a look at it and update my answer if necessary.

Comment: @leila You did something wrong. Take a look at your code. I tested the code I posted in the answer above with the latest OpenAI Python SDK version (i.e., `1.6.1`) right now, and I received the response as expected (i.e., `Hello! How can I assist you today?`).