# How do i fix this openai error for openai api and langchain api

Tags: openai-api, langchain

```
raise APIRemovedInV1(symbol=self._symbol)
```

openai.lib._old_api.APIRemovedInV1:

You tried to access openai.ChatCompletion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0 - see the README at https://github.com/openai/openai-python for the API.

You can run `openai migrate` to automatically upgrade your codebase to use the 1.0.0 interface.

Alternatively, you can pin your installation to the old version, e.g. `pip install openai==0.28`

A detailed migration guide is available here: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/discussions/742

i tried to fix the problem by going to the links it gve me but none of them worked out

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77506228/10347145).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenAI API error: "You tried to access openai.ChatCompletion, but this is no longer supported in openai>=1.0.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77505030/openai-api-error-you-tried-to-access-openai-chatcompletion-but-this-is-no-lon)